# Deploying a Node CLI to NPM, built with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I am having some trouble deploying a Node CLI tool to NPM. I am able to develop and test the tool without issue. I can even run `npm link` on the repo and it works as intended.

I can successfully publish and download the package, but when I run the tool the application crashes with the following message:

[image]

After checking the location where the package is installed, I noticed that the files inside of `/Commands` were not transpiled by TypeScript. Instead, the only files there are the `.ts` and the `.d.ts` files.

I am not sure why TypeScript is not building the `.js` files, it does it on my machine without problem. Even the `Index.ts` files gets transpiled to `Index.js`.

In case it matters, I am exporting the modules ESModules style, with `import` and `export`.

TSConfig file:
https://github.com/SammyIsra/ChecklistChecker/blob/master/tsconfig.json
It is the default file from `tsc init`, I believe, with some minor changes.

And link to the repo is here: https://github.com/SammyIsra/ChecklistChecker

Thank you for the help!

Comment: You didn't specify `files: ["index.ts"]` in your tsconfig.json

Comment: @unional that ended up not being the issue. It was more of a combination of setting an `outDir` on `tsconfig.json` and a `.npmignore` that would override the `.gitignore`. Thank you, tho!

Comment: Glad to hear you've figured it out

Answer (score 0):

I ended up realizing the issue was with both my TypeScript configuration as well as my NPM configuration.

On the TypeScript (`tsconfig.json` file) side:

- First, I set up my `outDir` and my `rootDir` to separate working and compiled files.
- Second, I made sure that my module type was `commonjs`

On the NPM (`package.json`) side:

- I set `main` to point to `./outDir/Index.js` and `types` to `./outDir/Index.d.ts`
- I set up a `prepare` script that would recompile the TS files. Basically, make it run `tsc -p ./tsconfig.json`.
- Lastly, I made an `.npmignore` file where I only included the dev folder, where all my TS files were.

You can read [here](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/nodejs.html#creating-typescript-node-modules) about how to prepare your TS to work with Node.

And you can read [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) about the `.npmignore` part, and [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#description) about the `npm prepare` part.

Lastly, you can find [here](https://github.com/SammyIsra/ChecklistChecker/issues/2) my issue on GitHub that I tried to keep up to date with my findings.